# How to retrieve only left table values no matching records from right table

Tags: sql, inner-join, outer-join

I have Two Tables Where i am match table 1 data with table 2 data.
How i can get the data from left table and no matching record from right table
means if any match found in the right table i need to omit that and the remaining value as a result

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between "INNER JOIN" and "OUTER JOIN"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38549/what-is-the-difference-between-inner-join-and-outer-join)

Comment: You don't say what the result looks like in rows with "no matching record from right table". PS This is a faq. Please always google many clear, concise & specific versions/phrasings of your question/problem/goal & read many answers. Add relevant keywords you discover to your searches. If you don't find an answer then post, using use one variant search for your title & keywords for your tags. Yet you have *tagged* this with outer-join so why do you have to ask a question. What exactly do you not understand?

Answer (score 1):

Try below query with left join and given condition of righttable.id is null - this will give you non matching rows

```
select * from lefttable left join righttable on lefttable.id=righttable.id
    where righttable.id is null
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT *
FROM L_TABLE L
LEFT JOIN R_TABLE R 
 ON L.id=R.id
WHERE R.id IS NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT table1.column1, table2.column2...
FROM table1
LEFT JOIN table2
ON table1.common_field = table2.common_field;
```

Comment: You meant table**1**.column2 ? :)

Comment: first you will get the field from table1 which has matching property to the table 2.
e.g
table1. field that exists in table2 column.

Comment: SELECT Customers.CustomerName, Orders.OrderID
FROM Customers
LEFT JOIN Orders ON Customers.CustomerID = Orders.CustomerID
ORDER BY Customers.CustomerName;

Comment: @ahmadizhar this code won't give the wanted result. It would also return the rows that exist in table 2.

Comment: if you want to just just unselect the data from table2 you may use then simple query using where clause like -> whereNotIn('table2.coloumn' ','=', $variable having id of table 1);

hope you got it, pardon any mistake !

Answer (score 0):

use left join with right table column in  where condition

```
    select t1.* from table1 t1 left join table2 t2 on t1.id=t2.id
   where t2.id is null
```